# Failed to use where condition

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have developed a app,now am in the need to use the where condition in my query to sort out the cars ranges from 75000 to 150000..but it doesnt return anything..Can anybody help me to solve this

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
        {
            mysql_query($qry);
     }
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars where (price<75000 and price>150000)");

    echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>color</th>
<th>cond</th>
<th>make</th>
<th>price</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";?>
   <td width=5%>
                <?php echo $row['id']; ?>

            </td>
  <td width=10%>
                <?php echo $row['color']; ?>
            </td>

  <td width=10%>
                <?php echo $row['cond']; ?>
            </td>

  <td width=10%>
                <?php echo $row['make']; ?>
            </td>
  <td width=10%>
                <?php echo $row['price']; ?>
            </td>
  <?php
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions please (These are deprecated). Instead, use mysqli or PDO

Comment: Is it possible for the same number to be less than 75000 and larger than 150000?

Comment: @bhttoan I like your comment, and that indeed just might fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition was wrong

```
SELECT * FROM cars 
where price > 75000 and price < 150000
            ^-----------------^--------------------here
```

You can also use

```
SELECT * FROM cars 
where price between 75000 and 150000
```

But that includes `75000` and `150000`

Comment: Thanks @ Juergen...It perfectly works,A timely help...thanks again

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when using between, will it also include 75000 and 15000 in the conditions?

Comment: Yes, BETWEEN is equivalent to price >= 75000 and price =< 150000

Answer (score 1):

As I see I think your WHERE clause is wrong.
`WHERE (price<75000 and price>150000)`, 
I think it should be:
`WHERE (price > 75000 AND price < 150000)`, also you can use
[BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) clause.

Comment: I think this answer are correct. I don't know why somebody downvoted this.

Comment: Tanks for voting, But I misspelled a little bit the answer.